# How can I call a method using ng-model in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to call a method through ng-model but it's not working properly
I am iterating through a ng-repeat. Inside the ng-repeat I have a ng-model(ex: ng-model="currentValue"). I want to set different values for ng-model in each iteration. Therefore I thought to call a js function like ng-model="setCurrentValue(parameterFrom-ng-repeat)" to set values. But it's not working. My question is, Is it possible to call functions with ng-model?. I already tried but couldn't find a way. Someone please give me an example or a solution for this

i am using angular material desgin (chips) to display some elements

1. there can be multiple methods in a selected operation
2. one method can contain multiple parameters
3. each parameter has 2 properties, key and value
4. i want to print the specific parameters for a given method each time
5. therfore i call a js method with each iteration to set method specific parameters

   ```
   <div ng-repeat= "methods in selectedOperation.methods">

       <md-chips ng-model='setParameterInfor(methods.parameters)'>
       <md-chip-template>
           <strong>{{$chip.key}} |</strong>
           <em>{{$chip.value}}</em>
           </md-chip-template>
       </md-chips>

   </div>
   ```

Comment: No. You can not call. To set different values for ng-model you can use $index inside ng-model

Comment: Can you let us know what you really want with a small example and a piece of html, js code? May be we can help you have a better of achieving this.

Comment: i have add a sample code above in my question

Answer (score 2):

No. It is not possible to call a function from 'ng-model'. When you bind something with ng-model it must be available for both reading and writing - e.g. a property/field on an object.